# Best way to Join two different grain Data

Tags: sql

How I can get the best optimized answer for below?

Input:

| Emp. | Dept | Emp_Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | 100 |
| 2 | a1 | 200 |
| 3 | a1 | 300 |
| 4 | a2 | 200 |
| 5 | a2 | 100 |

Output:

| Emp. | Dept | Emp_Salary | Dept_Total_Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | 100 | 600 |
| 2 | a1 | 200 | 600 |
| 3 | a1 | 300 | 600 |
| 4 | a2 | 200 | 300 |
| 5 | a2 | 100 | 300 |

How can I create this with best optimized way with 1 table scan only...I am able to do it with Subquery but would like how

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us your current subquery attempt.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
select Emp,Dept,Emp_Salary,
sum(Emp_Salary) over (PARTITION BY Dept ORDER BY Dept) as Dept_Total_Salary 
from Employee
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `SUM()` as an analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT Emp, Dept, Emp_Salary,
       SUM(Emp_Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept) AS Dept_Total_Salary 
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.*,
SUM(emp_salary) OVER(PARTITION BY dept) dept_toatl_salary
FROM employee e
ORDER BY emp;
```